# opening socket to google hangs on SYN_SENT

Tags: linux

I have 2 computers now: downloader (asus at4nm10t-i) with debian and desktop (asus sabertooth 990fx) with gentoo in the same network under NAT even with the same ethernet card: **RTL8111E**. Driver r8169 is compiled as module on both computers. Sometimes **in evenings** desktop cannot connect to google and all its services like now:

```
curl -v http://www.google.by
```

on downloader it received server's answer immediately. on desktop it hanged and when I ran in other terminal:

```
netstat -ntp | grep curl
>>tcp 0 1 192.168.0.7:54126 173.194.35.191:80 SYN_SENT 4876/curl
```

after 1-2 minutes it received server's answer. I was tried to change ip of network, mac address of desktop but nothing changed. When I was trying to connect to **another services except google**:

```
curl -v http://www.yahoo.com
```

both computers received answers immediately! Only when I rebooted desktop it begins to work with google services correctly

I cant understand what is this bug related to. In which bugtracker should I post this: r8169 or linux kernel or google?

PS. Desktop was checked with memtest: 5 passes - no errors

Comment: So your question is "where should you report the suspected bug"?

Comment: I cant understand what this bug is related to

Answer (score 3):

I had such problem for about a year and it has been disappeared (2012-2013).

Now I have another problem: short living time of tcp connections (11-12 2014).

I've checked almost all our internet providers in Belarus. It looks like all problems are connected with our core monopolist provider "beltelecom" and its "firewall".

Comment: It’s always sad to hear things like that. Although you probably won’t be able to access it, [here’s an in-depth report on internet freedom in Belarus](https://freedomhouse.org/report/freedom-net/2014/belarus).